# postgres select query on time column generate output wrong

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using postgres and I have this record that has the date_time column:

```
"2015-09-01 09:41:15"
```

When I do a psql query from pgadmin:

```
select * from table where date_time >= '2015-08-31' and date_time <= '2015-09-01'
```

This specific record does not show up even though I used = sign.  If i use <= '2015-09-02' it shows up.  Is there a way for the record to show up in a query using <= '2015-09-01' since its = to the time queried?

My time column:

```
date_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting the time. You could either cast your `date_time` field to date for the comparison (there's a performance toll, it can be very slow in large datasets):

```
select * from table 
where date_time >= '2015-08-31' and date_time::date <= '2015-09-01'
```

or you can cast your starting and ending dates to timestamp:

```
select * from table 
where date_time >= '2015-08-31' and date_time < ('2015-09-01'::date+1)::timestamp
```

Comment: this fixed my problem.  Thank you.

Comment: You may add straight explanation why this happens. And it's so because column is `timestamp without time zone` so string `'2015-09-01'` used for comparision is by default cast to `timestamp without time zone` too. In that case `PostgreSQL` set time do midnight so `'2015-09-01'` becomes `'2015-09-01 00:00:00':timestamp without time zone`.